# How to refresh Delphi IDE after applying a different value IDE SizeFont using ToolsApi?

Tags: delphi, toolsapi, otapi

I'm trying to refresh my IDE after applying a new font size. The code is:

```
procedure TEditorFontSizeController.ChangeFontSize(Delta: Integer);
var
  IdeServices: IOTAServices;
  EnvironmentOptions: IOTAEnvironmentOptions;
  CurValue: Integer;
  NewValue: Integer;
begin
  if not Supports(BorlandIDEServices, IOTAServices, IdeServices) then
    Exit;

  EnvironmentOptions := IdeServices.GetEnvironmentOptions;

  CurValue := EnvironmentOptions.Values['FontSize'];
  NewValue := CurValue + Delta;

  if (NewValue <= 7) or (NewValue >= 256) then
    Exit;

  EnvironmentOptions.Values['FontSize'] := NewValue;
  RefreshScreen;
end;
```

If I open the Editor Options from IDE I can see that the new values was applied correctly but it just reflect in the IDE when I click the OK button on the Tools Option Screen.
How to apply it directly from the code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914559/how-instruct-to-the-delphi-ide-refresh-the-modified-syntax-highlight-colors-usin?rq=1